# How to change the x-axis ticks from numbers to months

Tags: plotting, labeling

I have a `ListLinePlot`, for which the x-axis is time (November 2011 to January 2014). Now, when I plot it, the x-axis ticks run from 1 to 28 because the time duration is 28 months.

Is there a way to the x-axis ticks labelled in months?

My code:

```
ListLinePlot[{list1, list2}, 
  PlotLabel -> "November 2011 to January 2014", 
  PlotLegends -> {"All Users", "Fraudsters"}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Time", "Active Users per Month"}]
```

Comment: Take look at DateListPlot and TimeSeries

Comment: `DateListPlot[{list1, list2}, {2011, 11}, 
 DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort", " ", "YearShort"}]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Taking ilian's commentary suggestion and running with it, I found I could get a nice looking plot by tweaking some options.

```
SeedRandom[42]; data = {RandomInteger[{2000, 5000}, 28], RandomInteger[500, 28]};
ticks = DateRange[{2011, 11}, {2014, 2}, {2, "Month"}][[All, {1, 2}]]
```

> ```
> {{2011, 11}, {2012, 1}, {2012, 3}, {2012, 5}, {2012, 7}, {2012, 9}, {2012, 11}, 
>  {2013, 1}, {2013, 3}, {2013, 5}, {2013, 7}, {2013, 9}, {2013, 11}, {2014, 1}}
> ```

```
DateListPlot[data, {2011, 11},
  AspectRatio -> 1/3,
  DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthShort", "/", "YearShort"},
  PlotLabel -> "November 2011 to January 2014", 
  PlotLegends -> {"All Users", "Fraudsters"}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Date", "Active Users per Month"},
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {ticks, Automatic}},
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: plot]

Note the following tweaks:

- Custom ticks computed to get date ticks at two-mont intervals
- `FrameLabel` in place of `AxesLabel` because `DatePlot` produces a framed plot
- The bottom frame label is "Date" rather than "Time"
- Aspect ratio adjusted to be more appropriate (allows more tick labels)